# XML Sort to retain root data

Tags: c#, xml, linq, sorting

I am a C# Novice and have a problem which I hope someone can help me with?

I have a very small code snippet to Sort a large XML file.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public class XMLsort
{
 public static void Sort(string netMyFile, string netOutFile)
 {
    XElement root = XElement.Load(netMyFile);
    var orderedtabs = root.Elements("aidocument")
        .OrderBy(xtab => (string)xtab.Element("aidocumentheader").Element("accountno"))
        .ToArray();
    root.RemoveAll();
    foreach (XElement tab in orderedtabs)
        root.Add(tab);
    root.Save(netOutFile);
 }
}
```

This works very well however it is removing some root tags and I would like to know how to retain them in the sorted output?

Original XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252" ?>
<aitransmission xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="C:\Myschema\mysampleschema.xml">
<transmissionid>20120730DOCS</transmissionid>
<transmissiontime>23:02:19</transmissiontime>
<transmissiondate>2012-27-07</transmissiondate>
<transmissionsource>fromprd</transmissionsource>
<transmissioncount>71</transmissioncount>
    <aidocument documenttype="adv">
     [data]
    </aidocument>
    <aidocument documenttype="adv">
     [data]
    </aidocument>
    <aidocument documenttype="adv">
     [data]
    </aidocument>
</aitransmission>
```

Returned XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<aitransmission>
    <aidocument documenttype="adv">
     [sorted data]
    </aidocument>
    <aidocument documenttype="adv">
     [sorted data]
    </aidocument>
    <aidocument documenttype="adv">
     [sorted data]
    </aidocument>
```

So the 'transmission*' tags are being stripped.

Anybody can provide some assistance please?

Answer (score 1):

When you call `root.RemoveAll();` all the elements get removed. You actually want only the "reordered" elements to be removed. Rewrite your code so that it removes first the node, and then reinserts it.

Instead of

```
root.RemoveAll();
foreach (XElement tab in orderedtabs)
    root.Add(tab);
```

use

```
foreach (XElement tab in orderedtabs)
{
    tab.Remove();
    root.Add(tab);
}
```

The `Remove()` method does not require a specific location of the element and it also doesn't *delete* the element from memory; it just pops out the element from its parent.